# Kotlin single assignment filter and map

Tags: kotlin, filter

I want to make this a single assignment property

```
val movesWithMetaDataList: MutableList<PokemonMoveWithMetaData> = arrayListOf()
for (move in pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.moves) {
    for (metaData in pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.pokemonMoveMetaData) {
        if (move.name == metaData.moveName) {
            movesWithMetaDataList.add(
                PokemonMoveWithMetaData(
                    metaData, move
                )
            )
        }
    }
}
setPokemonMoves(movesWithMetaDataList.separateByGeneration())
```

Ive tried a bunch of things I think I want a filter and then a map but I'm struggling to figure it out, the lists can be different sizes

tried this

```
val movesWithMetaDataList = pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.moves.flatMap { move ->
    pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.pokemonMoveMetaData.map { metaData -> 
        if (metaData.moveName == move.name){
            PokemonMoveWithMetaData(
                metaData, move
            )
        }
    }
}
```

and this

```
val movesWithMetaDataList = pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.moves.flatMap { move ->
    pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.pokemonMoveMetaData.takeWhile {
        pokemonMoveMetaData -> move.name == pokemonMoveMetaData.moveName
    }.map { meta ->
        PokemonMoveWithMetaData(
            meta , move
        )
    }
}
```

and others

Comment: What do you mean with inline function here? Do you actually mean a "one-liner"?

Comment: No just inline, so the variable can be a val, like one assignment

Comment: Ok, that is usually not what is called "inline" in Kotlin. I think what you actually mean is to write it as a single expression, so you can assign it immediately to a val.

Comment: Yh after I replied I search inline and realised the same thank you I'll change the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should be it:

```
val movesWithMetaDataList = pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.moves
    .flatMap { move -> 
        pokemonWithMovesAndMetaData.pokemonMoveMetaData
            .filter { it.moveName == move.name }
            .map { PokemonMoveWithMetaData(it, move) }
    }
```

For each move I find the metadata for that move using `filter`, and then I use `map` to create `PokemonMoveWithMetaData` out of those. The `flatMap` function will flatten the lists created for each move/metadata-pair back into a single resulting list.

Comment: after some testing this works great many thanks